# Is there any way to include simple form fields after a request?

Tags: ruby, simple-form, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm using simple_form when the page loads the form is created, but I need and additional operation, I have to load a partial with multiple checkboxes, these correspond to data from a database, and the partial is rendered after the user click a button.

To do this I'm using js.erb with escape javascript, to render the partial. I already tried load with simple form directly, but I realize it didn't work as I expected.

```rb
$('.table-responsive.'+<%=@category_id%>).
  html(
    "<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'backend/research_participants/research_participants',
      locals: {companies: companies, category_id: category_id } ) %>"
  )
```

```rb
<% for company in @companies %>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <%= check_box_tag "#{category_id}company#{company.id}",
        company.id,
        checked = false,
        class: "companies_check_#{category_id}" %>
    </td>
    <td><%= company.trade_name %></td>
    <td><%= company.cnpj %></td>
    <td><%= company.contact&.email %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: what does current code show on your page after executing the js file?

Comment: I think I didn't understand your comment, it loads list o companies with checkboxes